# How do i use bootstrap and custom css i.e. home.module.css together in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, next.js

I'm trying to use multiple classes to get an elevated button effect and a fade animation on a bootstrap card. 
here is my code so far

index.js

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Nav from '../partials/nav'
import style from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import cx from 'classnames'
export default function Home() {
  function handleClick(e) {
      console.log(e)
  }
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossOrigin="anonymous"></link>
      </Head>
      <main>
        <Nav />
        <div className="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 category">
          <div className="col mb-4">
            <div className={cx[style.elevate,'card']} onClick={() => handleClick(1)}>
              <img src="https://placekitten.com/380/200" className="card-img" alt="..." />
              <div className="card-img-overlay text-white">
                <h5 className="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p className="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p className="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col mb-4">
            <div className="card text-white elevate" onClick={() => handleClick(2)}>
              <img src="https://placekitten.com/380/200" className="card-img" alt="..." />
              <div className="card-img-overlay">
                <h5 className="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p className="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p className="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col mb-4">
            <div className="card text-white elevate">
              <img src="https://placekitten.com/380/200" className="card-img" alt="..." />
              <div className="card-img-overlay">
                <h5 className="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p className="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p className="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col mb-4">
            <div className="card text-white elevate">
              <img src="https://placekitten.com/380/200" className="card-img" alt="..." />
              <div className="card-img-overlay">
                <h5 className="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p className="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p className="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossOrigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossOrigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossOrigin="anonymous"></script>
    </div>
  )
}
```

home.module.css

```
.elevate:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.elevate:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  /* A 1 second transition. */
}

.fade-in {
  animation: fadeIn ease 2s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn ease 2s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn ease 2s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn ease 2s;
}
```

how do I use classname='card text-white(bs) elevated(home)'?
some sights say use {style.class} but that makes me use only one class.
how do I get multiple css classes in the same quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Template literals, I am currently working on a nextjs project and came across the same issue, and using Template literals solved the issue for me.

**Egs.**

```
<div className={`d-flex ${classes.root} ${styles.parent}`}>
```

See if the same works for you.

Comment: Or `['d-flex', classes.root, styles.parent].join(" ")` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
className={"card text-white elevated"}
```

this can help you (https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)